# How can I see my SAML assertion when using Component Space

Tags: saml-2.0, component-space

I am using Component Space SAML 2.0 library to send an Single Sign On assertion to a partner site. They claim I am not sending my SAML assertion correctly. The library is high level so there's not much area for me to be messing it up, but I don't know how to see the message before i send it.

I would like to use the debugger (VS) or output the SAML XML token to the screen when I click a link on my page. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Are you doing this from a browser?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to capture it before you send it with your code/library... However...

Once it's "in" your browser... You can use TamperData, SAMLTracer, or the Developer tools in Firefox, the developer tools in Chrome, or a "proxy" like Fiddler or Charles. All of those will let you capture the encoded assertion.

Then, you can decode it using [this handy online tool](https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php). That will show you your assertion. SamlTracer will "decode" it automatically, IIRC.

Comment: Interestingly, I could figure out how to decode a SAMLRequest using C#, it ended up with all kinds of odd characters in it. I tried an online tool and it looked the same. But the one linked-to above works.

Comment: Did you BASE64 decode it and INFLATE, or vice versa?

Comment: Ah, maybe its the INFLATE. I didn't do that at all :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to turn on debugging in the web config file. This gave me a SAML assertion with comments that I could read.

Also using fiddler to look for the post worked as well. This gave me a encoded assertion that i could decode to see exactly what was being sent